# looping through array document in mongodb

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a MongoDB document called cartItems, which is an array.

```
"cartItems" : [    

    {
         "productID" : "2ae6b8013ade44ac60de872f",
        "quantity" : 5
    }, 

    {
        "productID" : "1ae2b8013ade32ac60de872d",
        "quantity" : 5
    },

    {
        "productID" : "6ae9b8023ade44ac60de8732",
        "quantity" : 5
    }, 

    {
        "productID" : "3ae9b96d3ade43ac60de8734",
        "quantity" : 5
    }
]
```

Now, I want to loop through it and obtain the values of "productID". 
I tried using .length (realized later it was a pretty noob thing to do) and it gave only the first productID.

```
  var user = Cart.find({"_id":Meteor.userId()}).fetch()[0];
      for(i=0;i<user.cartItems.length; i++){
          var id = new Mongo.ObjectID(user.cartItems[i].productID);
          console.log(id);
      }
```

I also tried using $size, but since my document is a dynamic array, I can't know how many products are in it before hand.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For simplification purposes, let's just say i want to print all 4 productIDs.

Comment: Use projection. `var user = Cart.find({"_id":Meteor.userId()}, {"cartItems.productID":1}).fetch()[0];`

Comment: yup. this works too.will be useful for what I want. Thanks! @Veeram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I don't have any experience with mongoDB, but here's an example of how to loop through each element of an object: 
(I understood that your problem is the `loop`, if not, please tell me)

```js
var user ={ "cartItems": [  
    {
      "productID": "2ae6b8013ade44ac60de872f",
      "quantity": 5
    }, 
    {
      "productID": "1ae2b8013ade32ac60de872d",
      "quantity": 5
    },
    {
      "productID": "6ae9b8023ade44ac60de8732",
      "quantity": 5
    }, 
    {
      "productID": "3ae9b96d3ade43ac60de8734",
      "quantity": 5
    }
]}

var cartItems = user.cartItems;
for (var item of cartItems){
   let id = item.productID;
   console.log("Id: " + id);
}
```

Probably, with mongo you can do in the same way, like this, using `for..of` :

```
var user = Cart.find({"_id":Meteor.userId()}).fetch()[0];
for(var item of user.cartItems){
   let id = new Mongo.ObjectID(item.productID);
   console.log(id);
}
```

Sorry if i'm saying bullshit here, because as I said, I have no experience in mongo, but maybe this helps...

Comment: Works for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: i have upvoted, but it won't show because i don't have the required rep

Answer (score 0):

try it in mongo shell or robomongo

```
 var user = db.col.find({}).toArray()[0];
 for(i=0;i<user.cartItems.length; i++){
    printjson(ObjectId(user.cartItems[i].productID));
 }
```